# XDebug - Cannot load - built with wrong configuration

Tags: php, xdebug

I am having a problem using xdebug w/PHP.

When I start Apache, xdebug does not load.  In the log file it says:

> "Cannot load Xdebug - it was built with configuration
>   API220131226,NTS,debug, whereas running engine is API220131226,NTS"

What does that mean?  Which of the two, PHP or xdebug, is built incorrectly?

I am using:

- Linux RHEL 7 on EC2
- PHP 5.6  (Built from Source)
- XDebug 2.3.3

PHP build options:

> ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs --with-mysqli --with-libdir=/lib64 --enable-mbstring --with-gettext --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/bin --enable-debug

XDebug build options:

> ./configure --with-libdir=/lib64

Other people on SO have mentioned that maybe the wrong phpize was being used.
I only have one copy of 'phpize' located in /user/local/bin
php-config --version returns 5.6.12

Comment: I would remove `--enable-debug` (or replace it with `--disable-debug`, I don't know what's the default) and compile `PHP` again.

Comment: Tried w/o enable-debug and w/ disable-debug.  No love.

Comment: Well, it doesn't hurt to try :-) My PHP is compiled with `--disable-debug` and my PHP extensions stays in `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/` and they work fine, but I didn't compile any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

When building PHP, make sure to use options --enable-debug --enable-phpdbg.

I had added options to the ./configure step.

The solution was to use "make distclean".